# how to get timestamp value with timezone abbreviation

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Is it possible to attach/include timezone abbreviation along with the timestamp value?. the below code returns the value something like this eg:*2-16-2017 @ 16:7:20*

I would like to include timezone abbreviation into this value? any thoughts

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime =  (currentdate.getMonth()+1) + "-"
                + currentdate.getDate()  + "-" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();alert(datetime)
```

Thanks,
Muthu

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can get timeZone abbreviations but definitely, you can get the offset.

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use `toTimeString()` instead of manually concatenating the time part:

```
currentdate.toTimeString() //"01:19:10 GMT+0400 (SAMT)"
```